# UIImage data method returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, parse-platform

I'm calling a method which connects to a database using parse to get an image.
All goes well and fine *inside* the method, but somehow it always returns an empty (nil) `UIImage` when I return the value.

This is my method:

```
- (UIImage *)getImage:(NSString *)objectId
{
  __block UIImage *image = nil;
  if(![objectId  isEqual:@""]){
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserPhoto"];
    [query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:objectId];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
      if(!error){
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
          PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
          [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
              image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
              NSLog(@"self.image: %@",self.image); //logs UIImage
            }
            else {
              NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
          }];
        }
      } else{
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
      }

    }];

  }
  return image; //returns nil
}
```

Why does this happen?

I tried to put the image into a global variable, didn't work either, store it in array, didn't work either.. I'm very curious to see the solution.

Comment: `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` runs in the background and completes long after your `return` statement is reached.

Comment: Ah that's right! So stupid.. I should probably use some sort of asynchronous method that blocks the return right?

Comment: @bdv better would be to change your `getImage` method to take a completion parameter, which it runs when the image is ready.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg that's a good thought. I'm having trouble implementing it however.. Do you have an example?

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

lets assume you want to update an ImageView somewhere in your code with the returned image.

```
[imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
              image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
              NSLog(@"self.image: %@",self.image); //logs UIImage
              [self updateImageViewWithImage:image];
            }
            else {
              NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
          }];
```

*Tip: UI changes only work on the main thread.

Comment: Good answer and good thought, however, the image needs to be loaded/created in a delegate method of an UI element, so unfortunately I can't use this approach.